# no me inserta los datos en mysql php .xls

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy tratando de importar datos de excel a mysql con php
pero este no me ejecuta bien el archvivo supuestamente lo esta guardando pero en mysql no me aparece nada

aqui esta el codigo

```
<?php
include "database.php";
include "class.upload.php";

if(isset($_FILES["name"])){
$up = new Upload($_FILES["name"]);
if($up->uploaded){
$up->Process("./uploads/");
if($up->processed){
/// leer el archivo excel
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$archivo = "uploads/".$up->file_dst_name;
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
$autonumero = $sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue();
$piloto_copiloto = $sheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue();
$clase = $sheet->getCell("C".$row)->getValue();
$vuelta = $sheet->getCell("D".$row)->getValue();
$largada = $sheet->getCell("E".$row)->getValue();
$llegada = $sheet->getCell("F".$row)->getValue();
$final = $sheet->getCell("G".$row)->getValue();
$penalizacion = $sheet->getCell("H".$row)->getValue();
$tiempofinal = $sheet->getCell("I".$row)->getValue();
$diferencia = $sheet->getCell("J".$row)->getValue();
//$cnv =(1-(floatval($mont_pagar) /$sdo_total)) *100;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$sql="INSERT INTO rallyracer ( autonumero, piloto_copiloto, clase, vuelta, largada, llegada, final, penalizacion, tiempofinal,penalizacion,actualizado_a) 
VALUES  ('$autonumero', '$piloto_copiloto', '$clase', '$vuelta','$largada' ,'$llegada','$final', '$tiempofinal', '$penalizacion','$now')";  $con->query($sql);

$cons=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


var_dump($sql);

}

unlink($archivo);

}   

}
}

?>
```

y aqui esta la parte de mysql
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero poder importar desde php a mysql pero no me lo permite

PD: el var_dump no me arroja nada esta en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

tienes un tema con la obtención de los datos de la planilla. Te paso el código que a mi me funcionó.

**Nota importante 1**: estoy asumiendo que la clase Upload, Process y la carga de la clase phpExcel, son correctas. Menciono esto porque en mi caso, utilizo otros métodos. Solo estoy cambiando el código de carga de la planilla.

**Nota importante 2**: no revisé si la carga posterior en la base de datos es correcta. Asumo que si porque le problema era que no había ningún dato para cargar por el error de carga de XLS.

Donde dice:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
```

Debiera decir

```
$inputFileType = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
$spreadsheet = $objReader->load($archivo);
$loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();
foreach ($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $xls[$loadedSheetName] = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($loadedSheetName)->toArray(null,true,true,true);
}
var_dump($xls);
```

Agregue un var_dump al array que tiene los datos recuperados del XLS.

Agregue un foreach para obtener las demás solapas de la planilla (si hubiera mas de una).

Ojalá esta info sea de utilidad.

Comment: que tal agrege como e dijiste para esto descarge phpoffice pero me aparece otro error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File" not found in

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\importexcel1-php\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php:115 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\importexcel1-php\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php(98): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile('uploads/ejemplo...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\importexcel1-php\import.php(13): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify('uploads/ejemplo...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\importexcel1-php\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php on line 115

Comment: aquies donde me marca el error 
 public static function createReaderForFile($filename)
    {
        File::assertFile($filename);

        // First, lucky guess by inspecting file extension
        $guessedReader = self::getReaderTypeFromExtension($filename);
        if ($guessedReader !== null) {
            $reader = self::createReader($guessedReader);

            // Let's see if we are lucky
            if (isset($reader) && $reader->canRead($filename)) {
                return $reader;
            }
        }

Comment: Parece que no está cargando la clase https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Lo que veo que lo estás cargando manualmente y es mas eficiente una carga via composer (https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation)

Comment: mira le avance algo y ahora me dio 
array(2) { ["Hoja1"]=> array(3) { [1]=> array(7) { ["A"]=> NULL ["B"]=> NULL ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> NULL ["E"]=> string(7) "llegada" ["F"]=> string(5) "final" ["G"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(7) { ["A"]=> NULL ["B"]=>

Comment: NULL ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> NULL ["E"]=> string(5) "10:04" ["F"]=> string(8) "10:06:38" ["G"]=> string(7) "#VALUE!" } [3]=> array(7) { ["A"]=> NULL ["B"]=> NULL ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> NULL ["E"]=> string(11) "11:36:38:79" ["F"]=> string(11) "03:38:34:80" ["G"]=> string(7) "#VALUE!" } } ["Hoja2"]=> array(7) { [1]=> array(10) { ["A"]=> string(1

Comment: 0) "autonumero" ["B"]=> string(6) "piloto" ["C"]=> string(5) "clase" ["D"]=> string(6) "vuelta" ["E"]=> string(7) "largada" ["F"]=> string(7) "llegada" ["G"]=> string(5) "final" ["H"]=> string(12) "penalizacion" ["I"]=> string(11) "t

Comment: iempofinal" ["J"]=> string(10) "diferencia" } [2]=> array(10) { ["A"]=> int(3) ["B"]=> string(28) "sabagustavo/mussano fernando" ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> int(1) ["E"]=> string(5) "10:04" ["F"]=> string(11) "10:06:38:98" ["G"]=> string(8) "02:30:98" ["H"]=> NULL ["I"]=> NULL ["J"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(10) { ["A"]=> int(19) ["B"]=> string(36) "zaldavia fabricio/ del bar

Comment: rio carlos" ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> int(1) ["E"]=> string(5) "10:06" ["F"]=> string(11) "10:09:08:98" ["G"]=> string(8) "02:50:98" ["H"]=> NULL ["I"]=> NULL ["J"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(10) { ["A"]=> int(1) ["B"]=> string(28) "dominguez diego/galindo edga" ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> int(1) ["E"]=> string(5) "10:08" ["F"]=> string(11) "10:09:30:98" ["G"]=> string(8) "02:58:98" ["H"]=> NULL ["I"]=> NULL ["J"]=> NULL } [5]=> array(10) { ["A"]=> NULL ["B"]=> NULL ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> NULL ["

Comment: Estas cerca amigo :). Ahora es solo cuestión de revisar que dato quieres guardar y vincular el array con el mysql. Como referencia podrías capturar la celda A1 de la solapa "prueba" (ese nombre lo invento) como $xls['prueba']['1']['A']. Suerte con ello.

Comment: YA LO HICE AHORA ME APARECEIO 
array(1) { ["Worksheet"]=> array(3) { [1]=> array(5) { ["A"]=> string(21) "3,sabagustavo/mussano" ["B"]=> string(41) "fernando,,1,10:04,10:06:38:98,02:30:98,,," ["C"]=> NULL ["D"]=> NULL ["E"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(5) { ["A"]=> string(11) "19,zaldavia" ["B"]=> string(9) "fabricio/" ["C"]=> string(3) "del" ["D"]=> string(6) "barrio" ["E"]=> string(39) "carlos,,1,10:06,10:09:08:98,02:50:98,,," } [3]=> array(5) { ["A"]=> string(11) "1,dominguez" ["B"]=> string(13) "diego/galindo" ["C"]=> string(37) "edga,,1,10:08,10:09:30:98,02:58:98,,," ["D"]=> NULL ["E"]=> NULL

Comment: LO DECLARE ASI 
foreach ($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $xls[$loadedSheetName] = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($loadedSheetName)->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    $xls['autonumero']['1']['A'];
    $xls['piloto_copiloto']['1']['B'];
    $xls['clase']['1']['C'];
    $xls['vuelta']['1']['D'];
    $xls['largada']['1']['E'];
    $xls['llegada']['1']['F'];
    $xls['final']['1']['G'];
    $xls['penalizacion']['1']['H'];
    $xls['tiempofinal']['1']['I'];
    $xls['diferencia']['1']['J'];

Comment: Bien. solo resta completar o mas bien asociar cada variable que necesitas al query de insert en mysql y listo. Buen trabajo!

Comment: Como te fue con esto? Anduvo?

Comment: no quedo yta que igual necesitaba meter unas variables

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. La consulta no es correcta, estás repitiendo dos veces la columna `penalizacion`, y omitiendo la columna `diferencia`. Luego, hay 11 nombres de columna y 10 valores. Para evitar este tipo de errores te recomiendo que escribas tus consultas identadas (como veremos más abajo), así podrás hacer una verificación rápida si fuera preciso.
2. Estás ejecutando dos veces la consulta, aquí: `$con->query($sql);` y aquí: `$con->query($sql);` Es el mismo método, con dos estilos distintos.
3. Es extraño que el `var_dump` no arroje nada. Pues lo que estarías imprimiendo sería la consulta SQL que no es otra cosa que una cadena.
4. No estás controlando posibles errores con respecto a la consulta. En la respuesta lo implementaremos. En cuanto al Excel y los datos que vienen de él lo dejo a tu cuidado, pues es algo que escapa al alcance de la respuesta por no tener contexto suficiente.
5. Es recomendable para este código usar consultas preparadas, cosa que haremos.

Te propongo esta solución la cual, repito, sólo atañe a la parte de la consulta. Si no funciona o no muestra nada, debes revisar la parte del archivo y controlar que realmente los datos que intentas leer en él existen.

```
if ($con) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO rallyracer 
              (autonumero, 
               piloto_copiloto, 
               clase, 
               vuelta, 
               largada, 
               llegada, 
               final, 
               penalizacion, 
               tiempofinal, 
               diferencia, 
               actualizado_a) 
            VALUES  
              (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
              
    if( $stmt=$con->prepare($sql) ) {
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $autonumero, $piloto_copiloto, $clase, $vuelta, 
                                         $largada, $llegada, $final, $penalizacion,
                                         $tiempofinal, $diferencia, $now);  
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $outPut="Consulta exitosa. Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
        } else {
            $outPut="Error en la consulta: ".$stmt->error;
        }
    } else {
        $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".$con->error;
    }

} else {
    $outPut="Error de conexión";
}
echo $outPut;
```

El código hace una verificación de todos los posibles errores, así como de los resultados exitosos. En todos los casos guardará información en la variable `$outPut` que será mostrada al final.

NÓTESE: que he hecho dos llamadas a la propiedad `error` de mysqli. Esa llamada te ayudará a conocer el motivo por el que código estaría fallando. No obstante, estás llamadas no son recomendables para la fase de producción de tu aplicación, deberías cambiarlas por mensajes de error genéricos o personalizados o incorporar tu propia política de manejo de errores.